# git submodule foreach execute command only in submodule with change

Tags: git

I have a repo git with 20 submodules. I make change inside 15 of these submodules.
Is there a way to easily commit and push in each submodule  with change. A command like `git submodule foreach 'git commit ... ; git push ...` that enter only inside submodule with change?

Answer (score 0):

If submodules haven't changed, when it tries to push it will say that is up-to date,and move on to the next module.

So shouldn't need to worry as a believe it compares that SHA at the HEAD and will only push if needed.

If you are having major issues with submodules try using a package manager to manage project dependencies.

Comment: I use `git submodule foreach '[...]'` when I have same modifications in a lot of submodule. I want to create a branche, checkout it, stage commit and push all changes with same commit message. Thereby I cant make a push because there is a new branch that has been created (and in submodule without change I don't want to see a new branch). Maybe my use of this command is not the expected one, and other solution are possible?